# No cursor motion capability occurs when startup linux script execute minicom script with at commands

Tags: linux, shell, startup, at-command

I have created a startup Linux script for a board that runs Debian jessie Armbian 8.1. I need at startup to run at command in a modem attached to it via USB interface. I've put the script inside rc.local:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
cd /home/user/Script/
sh script.sh
exit 0
```

In the folder Script I have a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
minicom -S at_command.txt
```

The at_command contains:

```
send at+creg=1
send exit
! killall minicom
```

The issue is that when I run the script manually it works correctly,
however when I start the the board the at commands do not execute.
Since the board is Debian I also followed the link: ttp://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html and to adapt the script to run according LSBInitScripts but I got the same behavior. When running `sudo /etc/init.d/myScript start` manually everything works great, but after Linux startup no at_command is executed. I added in the rc.local the following commands for debugging:

```
set -x;
exec 2>>/home/user/Script/minicom-rc.log;
date +"$0 %c" >&2
```

And in the generated log file I got this printout:

```
+ date +/etc/rc.local %c
/etc/rc.local Fri 02 Mar 2018 04:02:43 PM EET
+ cd /home/user/Script/
+ sh script.sh
No cursor motion capability (cm)
```

What I have done wrong?

Comment: Are the permissions of the files correct (the user running the scripts has read access to everything)? Can you add `set -x; exec 2>>/tmp/minicom-rc.log; date +"$0 %c" >&2` to the start of the `rc.d` script for debugging, and report back what you see in the log?  Dividing this into separate scripts which need absolute path names is rather clunky, it would be better if at least your user script could embed the `minicom` command sequence.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for you answer. The  user has read access to everything. I followed your advice for debug and in my updated post above you can see the relevant log file. The error seems to be No cursor motion capability (cm) but have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: I am guessing it is related to there being no terminal during startup. Maybe try `export TERM= linux-c-nc` before starting `minicom`.

Comment: ...without the space after `=`

Comment: If that doesn't work, maybe look into replacing `minicom` with something which was *designed* for scripted use, like `chat`.

Comment: The addition of "export TERM=linux-c-nc" solved the problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing it is related to there being no terminal during startup.

Maybe try adding the following line **before** starting `minicom`:

```
export TERM=linux-c-nc
```

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you alternatively use my [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program which is a program specifically made for sending AT commands to a modem from the command line (assuming the modem is /dev/ttyUSB0):

```
echo at+creg=1 | atinout - /dev/ttyUSB0 -
```

or possibly

```
atinout /home/user/at_commands.txt /dev/ttyUSB0 /dev/null
```